# SWT + Maven + Eclipse = java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-carbon-3346 or swt-carbon in swt.library.path

Tags: java, swt

I am trying to get a hello world SWT application going:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    Display display = new Display ();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.open ();
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    display.dispose ();
}
```

But I keep getting the following exception. I have the macosx version of org.eclipse.swt.carbon being used with eclipse/maven. Has anyone seen this before?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-carbon-3346 or swt-carbon in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:943)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:937)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:740)
    at com.wuntee.aat.command.adb.LogCat.main(LogCat.java:30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWT is implemented using native UI libraries - in this case, the Mac Carbon libraries - and requires some JNI code to marshal the SWT calls to the native Carbon calls.  Loading JNI libraries is a little bit different than normal classloading (the dynamic libraries must first be loaded with `System#loadLibrary`).

First, if you're on a 64 bit machine, make sure that you're passing the **`-d32`** argument to the JRE.  (ie, `java -d32 MyTestClass`).  The Carbon SWT libraries are 32 bit only and will not load on a 64 bit runtime.

By default, SWT tries to load the `.jnilib` dynamic libraries from a JAR file in your classpath - the library `libswt-carbon-3346.jnilib` should be in your `org.eclipse.swt.carbon.macosx...` JAR.  SWT will try to unzip this `jnilib` from your JAR into a temporary location and load that.

If it can't do this for whatever reason (`java.io.tmpdir` isn't writable, for example) then this will fail.  To work around this, you should extract `libswt-carbon-3346.jnilib` from the `org.eclipse.swt.carbon.macosx` JAR and follow the instructions that the exception provided.  (For example, set `swt.library.path` to the location of that jnilib.)

Unrelated to your actual question:  you're using SWT 3.3.  A lot of changes have been made since then, including the (likely preferable) Cocoa support.  Upgrading to the newest SWT libraries in the newest Eclipse may be very helpful.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but what if I am trying to keep things as 'clean' as possible? For example, I can see the .jnilib files in the swt library that I have imported from eclipse, and dont want to have a huge java -D... -D... -D... call when executing the application. How can I find out exactly what is going wrong?

Comment: I ended up downloading the newest SWT version, and it seems to be working properly. One issue I have had was when including the library in my local maven repo and including it in the project via m2eclipse, there is an error about the application not running as the main thread, but if I add it just as an external jar, it seems to work fine.... Thanks for the help.